# Calculated column within a JOIN using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I would like to display the SUM of the total amount of applications a person has made.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT custID, firstName, AppID, AppDate, Amount
FROM CustTable
JOIN AppTable ON custID = AppID
```

I have lots of rows per customer and would like to SUM the total application amount per customer

At the moment I see something like this:

```
1 | Jon | APP_1 | 200 
1 | Jon | APP_2 | 200
1 | Jon | APP_3 | 200
1 | Jon | APP_4 | 200
```

But I want (ideally with date ranges):

```
1 | Jon | APP_1 | 800
```

Comment: You really need APP_1 in the report?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
select custID, firstName, sum(Amount)
FROM CustTable
JOIN AppTable
ON custID = AppID
group by custID, firstName
```

which will return this:

```
1 | Jon | 800
```

Additionally, you can have the date range like this:

```
select custID, firstName, sum(Amount), 
       min(AppDate) firstDate, max(AppDate) lastDate, 
FROM CustTable
JOIN AppTable
ON custID = AppID
group by custID, firstName
```

which will return something like this:

```
1 | Jon | 800 | 2013-01-01 | 2013-01-28
```

Comment: APP_1 to APP_N seems to be the AppId, not the date...

Comment: @Quandary Duly noted, I read the question too fast. Just fixed that

Comment: Yep, happened to me, too ;) This is a silly question:)

Answer (score 0):

From the distincts in your table, i assume you want to have it grouped by AppDate as well:

```
SELECT custID, firstName, AppID, AppDate, SUM(Amount) AS Amount 
FROM CustTable
JOIN AppTable
ON custID = AppID

GROUP BY custID, firstName, AppID, AppDate
```

Your result list does not have an AppDate, so then when the values are not to be grouped by AppDate, you have to do it without:

```
SELECT custID, firstName, AppID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount 
FROM CustTable
JOIN AppTable
ON custID = AppID

GROUP BY custID, firstName, AppID
```

And if you want

```
1 | Jon | APP_1 | 800
```

as in your example, with the alphabetically first app id as name, it would be like this

```
SELECT custID, firstName, MIN(AppID) AS AppID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount 
FROM CustTable
JOIN AppTable
ON custID = AppID

GROUP BY custID, firstName
```

But to be honest, having APP_1 in the result does not make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic `group by` query:

```
SELECT custID, COUNT(*) as Num, SUM(Amount) as TotalAmount
FROM CustTable JOIN AppTable
     ON custID = AppID
group by custId
```

However, I don't see what the third column "APP1" is doing in the output.

Comment: and I don't see firstName in your output